# Convert sql query to eloquent

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to convert a query to a Laravel query but when I use `raw method` I can't make it work.

My query:

```
SELECT * FROM leagues
   WHERE SOUNDEX(name) 
      LIKE CONCAT('%',SUBSTRING(SOUNDEX('Eng. Premier League'),5),'%');
```

I couldn't find any docs online that answer me.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `WhereRaw()` to conver this query to Laravel Query Builder.

```
DB::table('leagues')
  ->whereRaw("SOUNDEX(name) 
             LIKE CONCAT('%',SUBSTRING(SOUNDEX('Eng. Premier League'),5),'%')");
```

if you don't prefer `WhereRaw()` then you have to use `DB::raw()` in your Conditions

```
DB::table('leagues')
  ->where( DB::raw('SOUNDEX(name)'), 'LIKE', DB::raw("CONCAT('%',SUBSTRING(SOUNDEX('Eng. Premier League'),5),'%')") );
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I assume `Eng. Premier League` will be some kind of variable, probably passed by the user. In that case, to make it safe it would better to have:

`->whereRaw("SOUNDEX(name) LIKE CONCAT('%',SUBSTRING(SOUNDEX(?),5),'%')", [$keyword])` where `$keyword` holds searched phrase.